# Cholesky factorization type error Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-methods

I'm trying nothing complicated but can't understand **why** it triggers this error (using Matlab's *R2016a* version).

I want to compute [Matlab's Cholesky factorization](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html;jsessionid=82c97f880c37e090a6ec23efd78b#f80-998739) `chol()` on `my_matrix` which is a `[2x2x3 double]`

```
my_matrix(:,:,1) = [  4.2534    0.4791;  0.4791    0.3522];
my_matrix(:,:,2) = [  0.9729    0.8723;  0.8723    2.6317];
my_matrix(:,:,3) = [  0.9886   -1.2244; -1.2244    3.0187];

chol(my_matrix)
```

However this throws the following error :

> Undefined function 'chol' for input arguments of type 'double' and
>   attributes 'full 3d real'.

Comment: How are you planning on getting a cholesky factorization on a 2 x 2 x 3 matrix? It's only defined for 2D matrices.

Comment: Ok so this is why it triggers an error. I agree it is a dumb mistake but I'm new to matlab and I find both the errors and the docs quite broad.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately Simulink has poor documentation. I had to think about what it actually meant mathematically at first.

Comment: I guess that's the first (best?) way to go and debug :) cheers anyway.

Comment: @downvoters could you explain and comment so that I my improve next questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Eli Sadoff, the cholesky factorization takes in a **2D matrix**. So this error meant I was using a 3D matrix instead of a 2D one. So I applied `chol()` to each of the last dimension instead.